# SharePoint 2010 Foundation Calculated Field based on Column Selection

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

This is my list:

- Currency (dropdown selections)
- Revenue
- Currency Rate
- USD Revenue

The calculation or If then statement I am having difficulty with is calculating the column for `USD Revenue`:

> If Currency=Brazilian Real then multiple Revenue * Currency Rate.

Much help appreciated.

Comment: How would you write the Formula in Excel ?  (using named cells) SharePoint is exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

So the formula goes like this

```
=IF(Currency="Brazilian Real",Revenue*[Currency Rate],Revenue)
```

This works on the condition you prescribed and calculates the USD Revenue based on the values provided for `Revenue` and `Currency Rate` columns.

If USD Revenue has to be calculated regardless of a specific currency, the formula would simply be:

```
=Revenue*[Currency Rate]
```

Comment: ok that works, now I have to add two additional currencies with rates to this, how would I go about that?  I do not have Workflow installed nor SharePoint designer, help is appreciated.  Thank you